# How to fix this socket_create error

Tags: php, sockets

This is my code:

```
<?php
function stribet2($inputstr, $deliLeft, $deliRight){
$posLeft = stripos($inputstr, $deliLeft) + strlen($deliLeft);
$posRight = stripos($inputstr, $deliRight, $posLeft);
return substr($inputstr, $posLeft, $posRight - $posLeft);
}
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);;
$result = socket_bind($socket, "localhost", 888);
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3);
socket_set_option($socket,SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>2, "usec"=>0));
$socket2 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$result2 = socket_bind($socket2, "127.0.0.1", 1337);
$result2 = socket_listen($socket2, 3);
socket_set_option($socket2,SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>2, "usec"=>0));
```

I get the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in (b)(directory)(/b).

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable sockets in your php.ini file

**If you are on windows**: open your php.ini file and around the line 650 region, find this:

```
;extension=php_sockets.dll
```

and change it to

```
extension=php_sockets.dll
```

(remove the semicolon in the beginning)

Comment: @Protruth Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: windows is what im running @Krimson

Comment: There is nothing named php.ini @Krimson

Comment: @Protruth Well, Im not sure whats going on if it isn't there. Is it possible for you to upload your php.ini file so I can have a look?

Comment: i dont have a php.ini file in any place.

Comment: @Protruth It should be in your php dir. Ok try this. make a php file and add the following code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` Then visit the page, it should show you the location of the php file under `Loaded Configuration File`